# how to make this sections dynamic on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

[how to make those sections dynamic that i can control changing them from wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoaPA.png)

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
<h3>Who is Bahgt Dar??</h3>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" class="img-responsive img-circle" style="display:inline" alt="" width="350" height="350">
<h3>Check <a style="color: white;">This To know!</a></h3>
```

Comment: you can use post_meta for additional content

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by using custom fields. And there is a great plugin for that.

It's called ***Advanced Custom Fields***. Give it a try: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

You can use them anywhere.